# Not able to figure out how to work with product size in django ecommerce website as select box for different products have same id

Tags: javascript, django

This is my html:

```
{% if product.id in list_cart %}
<div class="btn-group" style="display: none;">
<select class="selection-2 border" data-product={{product.id}} style="border: cadetblue;"
 name="size" required id="sizebox">
 {% for t in product.size.all %}
<option value="{{t}}" id="{{t}}">{{t}}</option>
 {% endfor %}
  </select>
  </div>
    {% else %}
 <div class="btn-group">
 <select class="selection-2 border" data-product={{product.id}} style="border: cadetblue;"
    name="size" required id="sizebox">
 {% for t in product.size.all %}
 <option value="{{t}}" id="{{t}}">{{t}}</option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>
  </div>
{% endif %}
```

And this is my javascript:

```
var updateBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('update-cart')

for (i=0;i<updateBtns.length;i++){
updateBtns[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
    var productId=this.dataset.product
    var action=this.dataset.action


    var sizebox = document.getElementById("sizebox");
    var size = sizebox.options[sizebox.selectedIndex].value;
    console.log(size)


    updateUserOrder(productId, action, size)
   
})
}
```

I am working on a basic django ecom. website. I have come across a problem which I am not able to solve. The problem is that on the products page of my website every product has a select box for size of the item and every select box has the same id (As i am iterating over the products). So whenever I choose a size for any product other than the first product the size selected from the first select box under first product goes to my database instead of the size selected under that product.
I want to figure out a way so that the size from the select box under a product is sent to the database instead of the size from first select box with id selectbox which is currently happening. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Try using loop counter and generate different id for select field,
use loop.index to generate value or use custom counter like

```
counter = 0
{%for ...%}
<option value="{{t}}" id="{{t+counter}}">{{t}}</option>
counter++
{%endfor%}
```

Or by using loop.index here's your code

```
{% if product.id in list_cart %}
<div class="btn-group" style="display: none;">
<select class="selection-2 border" data-product={{product.id}} style="border: cadetblue;"
 name="size" required id="sizebox">
 {% for t in product.size.all %}
<option value="{{t}}" id="{{t+loop.index}}">{{t}}</option>
 {% endfor %}
  </select>
  </div>
    {% else %}
 <div class="btn-group">
 <select class="selection-2 border" data-product={{product.id}} style="border: cadetblue;"
    name="size" required id="sizebox">
 {% for t in product.size.all %}
 <option value="{{t}}" id="{{t+loop.index}}">{{t}}</option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>
  </div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: So how do I alter my javascript to grab the collect value?

Comment: Also I think the problem is with the id of select tag and not option tag as in my javascript  I am using sizebox Id

Comment: You can concatenate id of product and sizebox and generate new id or make custom counter and user it select box